# failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, command

> Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I'm getting error like above when I try to run these files.

I create BNRStockHolding.h and BNRStockHolding.m

this is .h file
    #import

```
@interface BNRStockHolding : NSObject
//getter and setter
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float purchaseSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float currentSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int numberOfShares;
//method involving calculation
-(float)costInDollars;
-(float)valueInDollars;
@end
```

this is .m file

```
#import "BNRStockHolding.h"

@implementation BNRStockHolding
-(float)costInDollars{
    float total=([self purchaseSharePrice]*[self numberOfShares]);
    return total;

}

-(float)valueInDollars{
    float currenttotal=([self currentSharePrice]*[self numberOfShares]);
    return currenttotal;
}
@end
```

this is the code file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRStockHolding.h"
#import "BNRStockHolding.m"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
   //Creating instsances of BNRStockHolding to be stored in an array later
        BNRStockHolding *a=[[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];
        BNRStockHolding *b=[[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];
        BNRStockHolding *c=[[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];

    //Storing value of a here
        a.purchaseSharePrice=2.30;
        a.currentSharePrice=4.50;
        a.numberOfShares=40;
    //Storing value of b here
        b.purchaseSharePrice=12.19;
        b.currentSharePrice=10.56;
        b.numberOfShares=90;
    //Storing value of c here
        c.purchaseSharePrice=45.10;
        c.currentSharePrice=49.51;
        c.numberOfShares=210;
    //Creating an instance of NSArray class
        NSMutableArray *stockptr=[NSMutableArray array];
    //Add instances into the mutable array
        [stockptr addObject:a];
        [stockptr addObject:b];
        [stockptr addObject:c];

    //printing value
        for (BNRStockHolding* ptr in stockptr){
            NSLog(@"1 is %f, 2 is %f, 3 is    %d,%f,%f",ptr.purchaseSharePrice,ptr.currentSharePrice,ptr.numberOfShares, [ptr costInDollars],[ptr valueInDollars] );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also I'm storing .m and .h file inside the folder where main.m file is stored. Should I store .m and .h one folder above main.m file? Hope someone can solve this thing for me.

Comment: Ditch the `#import "BNRStockHolding.m"` line.

Comment: @rokjarc why? will it work? if so, why removing the line works?

Comment: @rokjarc no luck still fail

Comment: There might be some other problems in the code but you never want to import the non-header file. That's is what headers are for.

Comment: @rokjarc oh ok. Then where should .m and .h file be stored? can i store it in the folder where main.m is stored

Comment: It doesn't really matter where they are stored. They have to be added to the project and the header file also has to be added to the target.

Comment: @rokjarc oh it works now but i made 1 copy of .m and .h file ontop of main.m folder and i also store 1 copy of .m and .h file in the same folder as main.m.